# Not seeing all of a friend's Facebook posts

Tags: facebook

I can't see all my Facebook friend's timeline posts. For example, it goes from `Dec. 17, 2013` to `Dec. 24, 2012`. She says she has nothing blocked yet others can see these posts. There is no "More posts from date - date" option. "All Stories" was also selected.